# how to enable hotswap in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, hotswap, hotdeploy

I found a similar question from 2014 without answer or practical comment ( [Hot swapping code like Java in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27718015/hot-swapping-code-like-java-in-c-sharp)  ). I am quite unexperienced with DOT NET (my background is Java). I really don't want to compare IDEs or languages. My question is restricly to Visual Studio running C# and deploing to a local IIS Express during debugs. In case it is relevant, I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there isn't really hotswap in Visual Studio. BTW, the closest I could get is 
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> Edit and Continue > Enable Edit and Continue (uncheck)